# C++ character variable value of '\x1'

Tags: c++, character, ascii

I'm failing to understand why would the loop exit at the value of character variable i = '\x1'

```
  #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        char i;

        for (i = 1; i < 10, i++;)
        {       
            cout << i << endl;
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Can somebody please explain this behavior ?

Comment: Please help me to understand instead of downvoting. I'm new to C++

Comment: Use a debugger and step through the code.

Comment: @Borgleader You do realize that people new to programming are not aware of the concept of debugging, right?

Comment: my first comp sci class told us to use D.B.G. and never told us it was a debugger. They made it seem like some mysterious magical tool, and discouraged us from using the debugger... Jeez.

Comment: @dmg No I'm not, my first programming class introduced us to the debugger very early.

Comment: @dmg: OMG! Then, pleeeease, let's never mention the damn thing to them, so this won't change!

Comment: And, wow! Almost a decade after even VS introduced "modern" for-loop scoping (which was about a decade after it was invented), it seems people are still taught it wrong. `:(`

Comment: @Borgleader So let's assume, that everyone's first programming class did the same. A rather valid point. Let's assume everyone knows the same stuff and forget about this QA nonsense.

Comment: @sbi Might be better, than answering every single question with "debug it". This is a valid question, that can get a valid answer. And "no", that answer is not "debug it".

Comment: @dmg: So you want to not to mention a debugger to those who need to use it, because they don't know how to use it? Sounds like a good plan to keep yourself employed until your 110 years old. Count me in!

Comment: @dmg You can mention it like "This is the error of your ways, but for future reference in order to catch these issues on your own, you might want to learn how to use a debugger, because...", but shoving "debugger" in people's faces is not quite helpful.

Comment: @dmg "Might be better, than answering every single question with "debug it"." you seem to have forgotten a fairly important detail. I didn't *answer* the question with debug it, I commented on the question.

Comment: @Borgleader Yeah, quite the difference there. "Can't answer with that, as it will get closed. Better leave a pointless remark, that will in no way help OP or any future visitors. That will help the community!"

Comment: @dmg 'people new to programming are not aware of the concept of debugging,' - why not?  If they are not aware of that concept, the should not try and actually run anything.  They should stick to writing it, getting it to compile and link, and stop there.  They don't have the knowledge to effectively progress any further.

Comment: @MartinJames Let me rephrase that "people new to programming are not aware of the existence of a debugger"

Answer (score 2):

This is wrong

```
for (i = 1; i < 10, i++;)
               /* ^ should be ; */
```

Comment: But this is a valid syntax for statement. The program builds correctly.

Comment: It builds correctly because of the `;` at the end, but it doesn't work correctly does it?

Comment: What is so special about this character variable value of '\x1' ? What is its significance ?

Comment: I don't see the `'\x1'`?

Comment: When I run the program in Visual C++, I see value of i in the locals window as **1 '\x1'**. But when I try to edit/copy the value, I only see **'\x1'**

Comment: `std::cout` is printing the number `1` as an ascii character, `1` is not a printable ascii value, and hence the IDE is escaping the output value as `'\x1'`.

Comment: What value of i you see at your end when code is at return 0 statement ?

Comment: @peeppeep: Either you do not know what the problem is. Then you ask, read the answers carefully, and do try to understand them. _Or_ you already know what the problem is. Then you don't ask. However, coming here asking (what seems an absolute silly question to everyone having done C++ for more than a few months), but then trying to tell the answerers they are wrong as if you know the answer better than them, is bad, reflects badly on you and makes you appear a wannabe smartass.

Answer (score 1):

You only declared 3 regions for the loop, but put your increment statement in the middle area, and left your increment area empty. I have no idea which statement in the middle area your compiler will choose to execute. Best not to try to be cute and deceive your compiler. Let alone some colleague who will read your code years from now and go WTF???

A for loop has 3 distinct areas delimited by semi-colons:

1. The initialization area. You can declare as many variables in here as you want. These can be delimited by commas.
2. The test area. This is where an expression goes to test if the loop should continue.
3. The post loop area. This region of code gets executed after every loop.

Try to keep it simple. If it is going to be more complicated then use a while loop.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that i ends up being 1 is that when i++ is zero, which terminates the loop, then i will become 1 (That is what the form of the ++ operator you used does). As the other answered have pointed out, once you fix your code by moving i++ out of the condition by replacing the comma with a semicolon, then i will make it all the way to 10 as desired.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = 1; i < 10; i++)
```

You wrote `for` statement wrong.

Comment: But this is a valid syntax for statement. The program builds correctly.

Comment: Program can be compiled doesn't mean it is correct.

Comment: @peeppeep **building** correctly and **working** correctly are two distinct things.

Comment: What is so special about this character variable value of '\x1' ? What is its significance ?

Comment: @peeppeep it's nothing about '\x1', it's just because you've written for statement wrong and the loop exits after the first round.